# ODBC call SQLFetch vs SQLFetchScroll

Tags: c++, c, odbc

Is there any performance gain using `SQL_API SQLFetchScroll` over  `SQL_API SQLFetch`? I am working on a performance issue(need to load too much data from database) and found out that application uses `SQLFetch` i.e. fetches single row at a time. Why i am posting this question here because it seems that to implement block cursors in `SQLFetchScroll`, the cursor library repeatedly calls SQLFetch in the driver and return the cache data.Here is the [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).If anyone has already implemented `SQLFetchScroll`,please share the performance number.Actually i have pretty less time where in i am trying out some other ways to speed up and no time to try out this.I am sure many has already done it and implementing it won't be big task.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a couple people ask me this recently...

If you're utilizing a cursor library that emulates the operation of SQLFetchScroll by calling SQLFetch multiple times, then you likely won't see a performance benefit.

However, if you're using a driver that implements SQLFetchScroll naitively, you will see a performance gain.  I'll run some experiments using the Progress DataDirect drivers and update my post...I'll also get the test code posted to GitHub (I may be slow to do both though). In the meantime, below are a couple references, to backup my claims, but none provide the guidance with respect to performance numbers.

http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/odbc/allodbc/help.html#page/odbc%2Fusing-sqlextendedfetch-instead-of-sqlfetch.html

[https://www.amazon.com/Data-Access-Handbook-Application-Performance/dp/0137143931](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137143931)

Comment: So, where is your post and github link?

Comment: looks like i never followed through on this.  What are you most interested in learning/seeing?